# Pandas "fillna" ignores the "inplace=True" keyword

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` (fairly large, hard to reproduce &c), for which I observe this behavior:

```
>>> df.info(verbose=True,memory_usage=True,null_counts=True)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 49841 entries, 0 to 49878
Data columns (total 70 columns):
...
channel                                25101 non-null object
...
dtypes: bool(10), datetime64[ns](6), float64(2), int64(32), object(20)
memory usage: 23.7+ MB
>>> df.channel.fillna("Unknown",inplace=True)
>>> df.info(verbose=True,memory_usage=True,null_counts=True)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 49841 entries, 0 to 49878
Data columns (total 70 columns):
...
channel                                25101 non-null object
...
dtypes: bool(10), datetime64[ns](6), float64(2), int64(32), object(20)
memory usage: 23.7+ MB
```

IOW, it appears that `df.channel.fillna("Unknown",inplace=True)` has no effect.

How can that be? 
Is this a bug?
What am I doing wrong?!

PS. Summary from the comments:

- `df.is_copy` is `None`
- `df._is_view` is `False`
- `channel` is a column, not an attribute, because it is listed by `info`

Comment: what does `df[df.channel != df.channel.fillna('Unknown')]` returns?

Comment: I suspect it replaces nothing, as the inplace code you write is supposed to work if you df is not already a view

Comment: "inplace : boolean, default False

    If True, fill in place. Note: this will modify any other views on this object, (e.g. a no-copy slice for a column in a DataFrame).". Would that be the core of the problem?

Comment: Can you check `df.is_copy` and `df._is_view`?

Comment: @Boud : it returns a `[24740 rows x 70 columns]` dataframe.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: this means that `inplace=True` might modify _MORE_ that I expect. It modifies _LESS_.

Comment: @ayhan: `is_copy=None, is_view=False`

Comment: I could only reproduce by first assigning a column using dot notation (then with brackets). Does `df['channel'].fillna("Unknown",inplace=True)`  do the same?

Comment: @ayhan: same behavior as before. how is `df['channel']` different from `df.channel` here?

Comment: @ayhan: how did you reproduce it?!!!

Comment: `df.channel`  may refer to an attribute (created by mistake) instead of a column. It's a long shot but happens to me sometimes http://imgur.com/a/C3o07

Comment: @ayhan: if `channel` were an attribute, it would not have been listed by `df.info` as a column.

Comment: @ayhan you're right. `df.channel = pd.Series(...)`, followed by `df['channel'] = pd.Series(...)` leads to that weird behavior for me too

Comment: @ayhan: duplicate column names are the culprit, please see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#attribute-access):

> You can use attribute access to modify an existing element of a Series
>   or column of a DataFrame, but be careful; if you try to use attribute
>   access to create a new column, it fails silently, creating a new
>   attribute rather than a new column.

We suspect you assigned `df.channel` first, then `df['channel']` and this creates the unexpected behavior.

Comment: if `channel` were an attribute, it would not have been listed by `df.info` as a column.

Comment: I'm saying you did both

Comment: Search in your code if it is the case. What I guarantee you is ayhan mentioning this in the comment thread above, thus I tried and I reproduce the issue too.

Comment: Can I suggest a test where you replace all instances in your code from `df.channel` to `df['channel']` and see what's going on?

Comment: the first and only access to the column is `df.channel.fillna`. The `df` is returned by `sqlalchemy`

Comment: upvoted because it creates the described behavior, but it was _not_ the cause of my specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

The reason turned out to be the following `sqlalchemy` query:

```
select *
from table1 
join table2 
on table1.id = table2.id
```

The resulting DF has two columns named `id` and a total havoc ensues.

Solution:

```
select *
from table1 
join (select id as id2, ... from table2) t2 
on table1.id = t2.id2
```